# Adding an existing book to an existing user

Tags: java, list

```
I have a problem with a piece of java code :
I am trying to add an existing book to an existing user and replace a book that the user already has .
The relation is manyToMany and it work's , but if a user has 2 books and i am trying to replace one with the other it delete's all books and add's the new one
```

Edit: added code  userDto and bookDto and i am trying to add an existing book to an existing user but has to be replace one book from the set and leaves the other one there

```
public User updateUser(UserDto userDto){
    User user = userRepository.findByFirstName(userDto.getFirstName());
    Set<Book> bookSet = user.getBookSet();
    List<Long> selectedIdList =userDto.getGetIdList();
    List<Long> bookIdList = bookSet.stream().map(Book::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

    for(Long booksId : selectedIdList) {
        if (selectedIdList.contains(booksId)) {
            bookIdList.add(booksId);
        }else if(!selectedIdList.contains(booksId)){
            bookIdList.remove(booksId);
        }
    }

    return  user;
}
 @Data
public class UserDto {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private RoleType type;
    private Set<Book> bookSet;
    private List<Long> getIdList = new ArrayList<>();

    public RoleType getType() {
        return type;
    } 
    public void setType(RoleType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
@Data
public class BookDto {
    private Long id;
    private String bookName;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what each of the dto methods do? getGetIdList(), getBookSet() ...

Comment: If the idea is to update the book if its already there and add a book if not there, then can simply call add operation on the set. In what scenario do you have to call delete? It should be separate operation and not the same method.

Comment: i am not trying to update the book , i am trying to update the book set adding a book if doesn't exist  or if the user has 2  books and whants to replace a book with another book from the db .